# Is there Linux Live USB that works with Snow Leopard macbook pro from 2010 april

Tags: linux, macbook, liveusb

I was searching for a long time for a Linux Live USB that I can boot my MacBook Pro from. Is there such a distro I can install on Snow Leopard or Windows 7?

Update: I've found [this](http://blog.einval.com/2011/01/07#isohybrid_CDs):

> "isohybrid" CD images (..) are special in that as well as
>   the normal CD-based ISO9660 filesystem
>   they also contain a valid-looking
>   **DOS-style partition table**. Thus, if
>   you simply copy one of these images
>   raw to a USB stick **a normal PC BIOS
>   will boot** the image directly. (...)
>   Finally: I'd like to add support into
>   xorriso for creating the nasty HFS
>   **hybrid images that are needed for
>   booting Macs**. The code that does this
>   in cdrkit is probably some of the
>   worst that I've ever worked with, and
>   I'd like to get away from it. If only
>   Apple hadn't stupidly built their
>   proprietary platform around this 
>   and had used open standards instead

Comment: Booting Linux off USB on a Mactel machine is not well-supported.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu would work on your Mac. [Download it](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) and follow the instructions in step 2 for creating a USB stick on a Mac.

Comment: Did you even read the question? He wants to boot it from a Mac. Not make a LiveUSB with a Mac. Those instructions make a useless LiveUSB that DOES NOT WORK WITH A MAC!